# WSUS Replica Downstream Without Computer Management at Central Server

Tags: wsus

I have a Windows Datacenter 2022 WSUS Server. However, from what I understand the computer groups and computers need to exist in the central WSUS server (not replica). Downstream replica server is managed by a different admin group than the replica server (and Active Directory is different for the replica domain).

How can I push updates to the downstream replica WSUS server without requiring that my domain computers or groups exist in the central WSUS server?